# Access 365 - Error When Populating Unbound Text Field from Combo Box

Tags: ms-access, combobox, textbox, populate

Sorry in advance for the long description, but it seemed like the prudent course of action.

I am having a problem getting a combo box to correctly populate a text field in a subform.

Based on surfing the web and some helpful guidance on adding VBA to forms earlier this week here is what I tried.

I have created a table `tblPgo` showing several probabilities of a project proceeding and a corresponding descriptions.

[image]

I have a second table `tblDetails` containing information about the items we are selling.

These two tables interact in a subform `tblDetals subform`.

I added a combo box `cmbPgoValue` to the subform.  The combo box gets its data from `tblPgo`

Control Source is `Pgo`

Row Source is `SELECT [tblPgo].[PgoID], [tblPgo].[Pgo], [tblPgo].[PgoDescription] FROM tblPgo ORDER BY [Pgo];`

The Row Source syntax was created by the combo box wizard.

In the subform, I created an unbound text box called `Pgo Description` to receive the PgoDecription text corresponding to the selected Pgo value from the combo box.

`cmbPgoValue` has the following After Update Event code

```
Private Sub cmbPgoValue_AfterUpdate()

Me.PgoDescription = Me.cmbPgoValue.Column(2)

End Sub
```

When I use the combo box to select a Pgo value, the correct Pgo Description populates the current record and the record below it.  When I try completing the incorrectly populated record, I get an error about duplicating indexes, etc.

I've tried bounding the text box, but it does not seem to help.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There is a field named Pgo in tblDetails? Advise not to use same exact field name in multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is to be expected with UNBOUND textbox. There is only the one Description textbox so all records will show the same info. Should not be duplicating this info into tblDetails. Instead of VBA, just have expression in textbox ControlSource:

`=cmbPgoValue.Column(2)`

Comment: Thanks again.  Something tells me I will be owing you bottle of nice wine when my project is done.

Comment: The ControlSource expression worked as predicted.  New problem (or old problem I didn't elaborate on in great detail).  When entering a second record under Blue Widget and use the combo box to give it a Pgo value, the description populates, but I get the following error `The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship..."`  Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds like need to post a new question. And sounds like a design issue.

Comment: Ugh.  Will need to tackle this tomorrow.